# How does Linux network driver signal the NIC card that the data is ready to be transmit

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ethernet, nic

My driver is [sky2 network driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/drivers/net/ethernet/marvell/sky2.c).

I found the function `static netdev_tx_t sky2_xmit_frame` that maps to the Linux `net_device_ops: .ndo_start_xmit`.

The comment above this function is:

> Put one packet in ring for transmit. A single packet can generate
>   multiple list elements, and the number of ring elements will probably
>   be less than the number of list elements used.

However, I do not find the code for signaling the hardware to transmit the packet after the driver puts it in the ring buffer.

Any idea about how does sky2 signal the Marvell NIC or other drivers signal related devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It writes to a memory mapped IO region. I assume it's line [1987 (v4.16):](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/drivers/net/ethernet/marvell/sky2.c#L1987)

```
sky2_put_idx(hw, txqaddr[sky2->port], sky2->tx_prod);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that this function can update the latest TX buffer index on the NIC. However, I'm wondering does the NIC automatically check the latest index after every write?

Comment: @S.Wan The trick with MMIO is that to you, the kernel, it looks like a simple memory access, but to the NIC it's more like a protocol with ReadRequest and WriteRequest PDUs. When a WriteRequest to one of the Tx queue addresses comes in, it can be handled immediately. There need not be a memory at all, only a memory-like "interface".